# Using simulation to estimate type-I error in Bayesian Tests

Tags: bayesian, frequentist, type-i-and-ii-errors

When doing a bayesian test, it is possible to estimate a "type-I error" of the test procedure by generating data from the null-hypothesis and running the bayesian test procedure several times. While the use of Type-I errors does not make sense in a pure bayesian framework, this mixed methodology seems to work OK and is even recommended by FDA when using bayesian analysis in clinical trials. Are there any *practical* negative consequences of using this mixed methodology? E.g. cases where the estimated type-I error will be wrong?

I'm thinking of this for instance in the context of Bayesian A/B-testing, where we have two different Bernoulli random variables, $A$ and $B$, and wish to find out whether $p_A > p_B$ or $p_A < p_B$. In order to calculate the posterior based on our data $D$, We can use a Bernoulli likelihood and a Beta(1,1) prior for both $A$ and $B$. The test could involve sampling data from $A$ or $B$ for a fixed number of samples or until some stopping criterion is fulfilled, for instance when either $P(p_A > p_B | D) > 0.95$ or $P(p_A < p_B | D) > 0.95$, and then concluding whether $p_A > p_B$ or $p_A < p_B$ based on the posterior $P(p_A > p_B | D)$.

Comment: Rather than asking people to check other entries, could you write a summary of the method and of your difficulties with it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean - I don't really have any difficulties with the methodology, I was more interested in knowing if there *are* any obvious problems with this methodology.

Comment: You make links to other pages but rather than expecting readers to go through those pages it would be more considerate to summarise the problem in a self-contained manner. Right now it does not read self-contained.

Comment: Ah, I see. I tried to make the question more self-contained now, let me know if it needs more clarification.